# How do I get Flickr user Id in php/js

Tags: flickr

I want to get Flickr User ID like `"12037949632@N01"` this one. But can't figure out anything.

I have visited Flickr API and found this

```
<user nsid="12037949632@N01"><username>Stewart</username></user>
```

But how I get this, how do I call or request? Any tutorial or code.

Why I need this userID? Because I want to display dynamically user's flickr photos in my site. Like all photographer's photos in one place.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format your inline code sample by using backticks so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [flickr.people.findByUsername.html](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.findByUsername.html) API method.

In PHP, you can use [phpflickr](https://github.com/dan-coulter/phpflickr) library after you [get your API key](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html):

```
$apiKey = '<your api key>';
$f = new phpFlickr($apiKey);
$response = $f->people_findByUsername($username);
var_dump($response);
```